# Сортировка постов по порядку в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, как настроить вывод постов по произвольному полю. Имеется поле Артикль с номерами (в админке посты указаны вразнобой):

000013
000012
000011
000010
000009
000008
000007
...
000001

В данный момент стоят такие настройки:

```
               $posts = get_posts( array(
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'category_name'    => 'catalog',
                    'orderby'   => 'article',       
                    'order'       => 'DESC',
                    'post_type'   => 'post',
                    'suppress_filters' => true, 
                ) );
```

И на сайте поля сортируются таким образом:

000013
000012
000011
000010
000001
000002
000003
...
000009.

Кто знает как сделать, чтобы посты сортировались, как указано вверху.

Answer (score 1):

```
$posts = get_posts( [
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'category_name'    => 'catalog',
                'post_type'   => 'post',
                'suppress_filters' => true, 
                // Сортировка
                'orderby'  => 'meta_key_num' // Сортировка по ЧИСЛОВОМУ мета полю
                'order'    => 'DESC' // Сортировка от большего к меньшему
                'meta_key' => 'your-field-name' // Название вашего метаполя
            ) );
```